# WordPress installation not working after migrating from Server to XAMPP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, xampp

Some hours ago I've migrated my WordPress installation from my Server to XAMPP (under Mac).

I've also updated the URL's in the database, changed the `wp-config.php` and all the needed stuff. I've did this a lot of times but this time I've a problem and I can't find it.

When I open now the console, I'm getting about 100 errors. The first error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

So I've checked the network to verify if jQuery is loaded:

```
Request URL: http://develop.infran.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from memory cache)
Remote Address: 192.168.64.2:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

So no clue whats wrong here. If you wondering, I've mapped the URL `develop.infran.de` to the **IP** from **XAMPP** in my `hosts` config.

Comment: Could you provide more logs of the errors ? It should say which token is invalid.
You should also provide the source HTML where this happens, and finally, you have checked that jQuery is loaded, but have you checked that jQuery is loaded BEFORE your script ?

Comment: It seems that this is a problem with UTF-8 on XAMPP servers or FileZilla during the download of the WordPress folder. I don't know how to fix this yet.